# Burn ExePackage unable to find msi

Tags: wix, installation, bootstrapper, burn

I have a Setup project which contains `BootstrapperFile` items in the wixproj and using the `GenerateBootstrapper` generates a setup.exe which bootstraps 6 items (e.g. .NET 4.0, Adobe Acrobat Reader, Adobe Flash Player).

This setup.exe works by itself. I can uninstall Adobe Acrobat Reader and then using setup.exe reinstall it. The files in `OutDir` are `Folder1`, `Folder2` ... `Folder6` for the prerequisites and then setup.msi and setup.exe.

I have another Setup project which generates a App.msi. This App.msi can be installed by itself.

I would now like to Chain the above two items in the following order: setup.exe -> App.msi

I am able to Chain App.msi alone and it works.

The Chain elements looks like below:

```
<Chain>
      <ExePackage SourceFile="$(var.SetupPrereqs.TargetDir)setup.exe" Cache="no" ></ExePackage>
      <MsiPackage SourceFile="$(var.Setup.TargetDir)App.msi" ForcePerMachine="yes" Cache="no"></MsiPackage>
    </Chain>
```

However I am unable to chain the ExePackage. I get the following error:

```
[0984:2360][2013-07-25T11:19:34]e000: Error 0x80070643: Process returned error: 0x643
[0984:2360][2013-07-25T11:19:34]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute EXE package.
[0FD8:2240][2013-07-25T11:19:34]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to configure per-machine EXE package.
[0FD8:2240][2013-07-25T11:19:34]i319: Applied execute package: setup.exe, result: 0x80070643, restart: None
[0FD8:2240][2013-07-25T11:19:34]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute EXE package.
```

The VS log did the following:

```
Line 19: 'Adobe Reader XI' RunCheck result: No Install Needed
Line 37: 'Windows Media Player 11' RunCheck result: No Install Needed
Line 70: 'Windows Installer 4.5' RunCheck result: No Install Needed
Line 92: 'Adobe Flash Player 11 ActiveX' RunCheck result: No Install Needed
Line 106: 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4 (x86 and x64)' RunCheck result: No Install Needed
Line 116: 'Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Report Viewer' RunCheck result: No Install Needed
```

It failed here:
*Launching Application.
Error: Unable to locate application file 'setup.msi'.*

How do I ensure that the setup.exe finds the setup.msi in the end?

I actually do not need the setup.msi to run. It is enough if the control comes back to the Chain.

Comment: `0x643=1603 "A fatal error occurred during installation"` I'm not sure if the VS bootstrapper would create that error code itself or if it is just passing it along from one of its packages. In any case, the VS bootstrapper should be creating its own log.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the msi file as a Payload element inside the ExePackage solved the issue.

```
<ExePackage SourceFile="$(var.SetupPrereqs.TargetDir)setup.exe">
        <Payload SourceFile="$(var.SetupPrereqs.TargetDir)setup.msi"></Payload>
</ExePackage>
```